# Egui: How to disable capturing mouse movement?

Tags: rust, egui

I'm making an app with egui (Rust) and i want to disable the window from capturing mouse movement, i can't find anything in the context creation that allows me to do so.

```
run_native(
    NativeOptions::default(),
    Box::new(|ctx| {
        ctx.egui_ctx.set_mouse_capture(false); // This is just for the purpose of explaining what i want, set_mouse_capture doesn't exist.
        Box::new(MyApp)
    }
);
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'capturing mouse'?

Comment: @Finomnis Capture mouse events; clicks, hover, movements, etc..

Comment: Why not just define a variable that makes your program ignore the events?

Comment: @Finomnis How can i achieve this?

Comment: You just define a global `AtomicBool` somewhere that indicates if the events should be ignored, and then in every event handler you read the `AtomicBool`. If it returns `true`, just don't do anything in the event handlers. I'm not deep into `egui` though, maybe `egui` works different than I think.